# Node.js: Cannot find module 'index' when using Request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda, request

NOOB warning!

Creating a simple Lambda function that gets called for Amazona Alexa Intent. I cannot for the life of me get the basic Response module working.

Seems similar to this problem:
[node.js: cannot find module 'request'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482600/node-js-cannot-find-module-request)

Except that my error is:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'index'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:353:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:12:17)"
  ]
}
```

Do I have to install more modules?   I tried doing 'npm install index' into the same directory but that didn't help.

Please help!  I'm wasting HUGE amounts of time with this...
(is there a way to make a JSON API call from a Lambda function without this module??)

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32523358/560050

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS Lambda Function is returning "Cannot find module 'index'" yet the handler in the config is set to index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664313/aws-lambda-function-is-returning-cannot-find-module-index-yet-the-handler-in)