# aws lambda can't find index.handler

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying out aws lambda for nodejs, starting with the example, i can't seem to be able to resolve index.handler. i've make sure index.js is in the root directory. appreciate your help.

(EDIT) i'm using the example code from AWS website

```
const https = require('https')
let url = "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/welcome.html"   

exports.handler = async function(event) {
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        resolve(res.statusCode)
      }).on('error', (e) => {
        reject(Error(e))
      })
    })
  return promise
}
```

[index.js and test execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSo4C.png)

Comment: need share code instead of image

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to have good experience using the platform, you need to provide details or the actual screenshot of your problem in order to get help from others. Your question is very short or general. Good luck

Comment: @MERN thanks. i just added the code. i use a sample code from AWS documentation.

Comment: @AramisNSR the link goes to the actual screen shot of the folder structure, the code and the test execution error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31664313/aws-lambda-function-is-returning-cannot-find-module-index-yet-the-handler-in

Comment: @devcc before your edit, during the review there was no code segment to your question. thanks for providing better quality question.

Comment: @MERN the screen shot shows the correct folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

my error was simply because after saving the edit in the online editor, i need to "Deploy" the save. See [deploy button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDL9v.png)